# Browse features in cluster won't work in ArcGIS Web App

Tags: arcgis-online, clustering, popup, arcgis-web-appbuilder

After creating and configuring a web app i realized that the "browse features function" included in the cluster pop-up does not work properly when clicking a point layer's cluster icon. After showing the first feature contained in the cluster, upon clicking the right arrow to move to the next one, the cluster pop-up disappears. This does not happen in the web map upon which the app is built, where the browse features function works as intended. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the app created or do you know which web app template you used?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't at this moment share the app. I've used the web app builder and the foldable theme. The point layer where the problem appears is published as a feature service.